# npm install force to not use binary cache and rebuild from source, skip prebuild-install

Tags: node.js, npm, node-gyp

I'm trying to diagnose a problem that happens on someone else machine while compiling `kerberos` using node-gyp. We are simply doing `npm install run-rs` which depends on `kerberos`, my machine uses prebuilt packages, but there are no prebuilt for his and an error happen.

I want to reproduce the error by forcing node to rebuild those packages, but I've not been able to.

I tried this command:

```sh
npm rebuild
# also this:
npm rebuild kerberos
```

But it didn't rebuild any packages from source. I know this since I don't have `xcrun` in this particular shell, which is required by `node-gyp`. I just want to skip `prebuild-install`

Then I tried this:

```sh
npm install kerberos --no-binray-cache
```

But no differences.

Is there a way to trigger a rebuild for a node package?